# What the difference between the blank and nullable in the grails domain class constraints?

Tags: grails, groovy, constraints, grails-domain-class

Just saw this example for grails constraint, But why not just leave blank as constraint, i think both `nullable` and `blank` will have same function.

```
class User {
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String passwordHash

    static constraints = {
        firstName blank: false, nullable: false
        lastName blank: false, nullable: false
        passwordHash blank: false, nullable: false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all domain class properties are not nullable (i.e. they have an implicit `nullable: false` constraint).

**Constraints:**

- `blank` - Validates that a String value is not blank. Set to `false` if a string value cannot be blank.

If the string is `null`, it won’t validate with `blank: true`. In this case, set the `nullable` constraint to `true`.

- `nullable` - Allows a property to be set to `null`. By default Grails does not allow `null` values for properties. - *defaults* to `false`. 
  Set to true if the property allows null values.

> But why not just leave blank as constraint, i think both nullable and blank will have same function

Web requests resulting from form submissions will have **blank strings, not null**, for input fields that have no value. Keep this in mind when doing mass property binding to properties that are not nullable. The default behavior is such that a blank string will not validate for `nullable: false` since the data binder will convert `blank` strings to `null`. This includes empty strings and blank strings.

A blank string is any string such that the `trim()` method returns an empty string. To turn off the conversion of empty strings to `null` set the `grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull` property to `false` in application.groovy.

Please refer [documentation](https://docs.grails.org/4.0.0/guide/validation.html) for more details.

Hope this will helps you.